# cross domain ajax query without answer

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

Trying to do a simple cross origin request. Working with ajax-cross-origin and set my own "proxy" to do the work. The weird thing is I don't receive any answer, either the success message neither an error.

```
        $.ajax({
            crossOrigin: true,
            proxy: 'proxylink.php',
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res) {
                //var headline = $(res.responseText).find('title').text();
                $('#success').html(res.responseText).text();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            $('#error').html(msg);
        },
        }
```

My proxy file:

```
<?php
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : false;
if(!$url) exit;

$referer = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) : false;
$is_allowed = $referer && strpos($referer, strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) !== false; //deny abuse of your proxy from outside your site

$string = ($is_allowed) ? utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url)) : 'You are not allowed to use this proxy!';
$json = json_encode($string);
$callback = (isset($_GET['callback'])) ? $_GET['callback'] : false;
if($callback){
    $jsonp = "$callback($json)";
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
    echo $jsonp;
    exit;
}
echo $json;
?>
```

If I do a console.log or alert (for a string) inside success, it writes in console, so I assume the ajax call is returning success. But I can't work the res returned value.

Any clue in what's going on?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `res`? Also remove `crossOrigin` as it's not needed

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't return any value. But the link I sent to ajax call is correct and checked it. I don't know how to handle this "error" and how to know what's going on.

Comment: You stated it writes to the console, so what is the value shown there?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. I already corrected my setence. I was trying to mean that If I make something like alert("Hello") inside the success function, it works, so I assume it's returning a success and not an error. But the res var is empty.

Comment: In that case it sounds like the problem is in your `proxylink.php` file, not the JS. Also note that `proxy` is not a standard property of `$.ajax`, so you may still be calling the external domain directly and hitting a CORS error. You need to implement your proxy URL manually

Comment: do you get something when you GET proxylink.php directly in your browser ?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that's a problem with proxy. When using directly in browser, getting a message "You are not allowed to use this proxy!" . Anyone faced this problem using ajax-cross-origin plugin? Just to point that I don't want any data as JSON, I'd try to get the full page source code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `proxylink.php` I think you should use it like this:

```
       $.ajax({
        crossOrigin: true,
        url: 'proxylink.php',
        data: {url:url},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            //var headline = $(res.responseText).find('title').text();
            $('#success').html(res.responseText).text();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        $('#error').html(msg);
    },
    }
```

Comment: Still the same. Nothing as output.

Comment: if you remove the crossOrigin:true ?

Comment: corssorigin is from the plugin itself. It needs to be enabled to make the request and use the proxy.